# Random Variable question

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X\in\{1,2,\cdots\}$ be the number of tosses until you first see heads and:

$$P_r(X=k) = P_r((\text T,\text T,\text T,…,\text T,\text H)) = \frac1{2^k}.$$

It follows that

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=?$$

What $E(X)$?

I am very confused on this anyone can explain this to me?

Comment: Have you been taught about 'expectations' yet? Here $E(X)$ is the expectation of random variable $X$

Comment: also that's not $E(X)$. correct one is $$E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x \frac{1}{2^x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ has a geometric distribution (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).